# ReactJS: NavBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to realize in the Navbar the possibility to change the language. I have use this code:

```
<div className="nav-mobile">
        <div className="link-list-wrapper collapse" id="menu1">
          <nav>
                  <ul className="link-list">
                    <li><a className="list-item " onClick={this.changeLan.bind(this, this.ita)}>ITA</a></li>
                    <li><a className="list-item " onClick={this.changeLan.bind(this, this.eng)}>ENG</a></li>
                  </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I would ask you:

1. How can I do to activate the language choosen in the nav-bar (not in the site, only in the navbar)? I have read the possibility to do:

   ```
             <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
             <li><a class="list-item active" href="#">Link 2 Active</a></li>
   ```

But I would to "active" only the button choosen not always active like in the code.

2. Do you know why when I pass the mouse over the link appears in this way? As it is not a link.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the react code please. As it will need state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## create a state for your selected language name it `lang` for example

```js
const { lang } = this.state
...

<li>
  <a 
    className={`list-item ${lang === 'ita' ? 'active': ''}`} 
    onClick={this.setState({lang: 'ita'})}
  >
  ITA
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a 
    className={`list-item ${lang === 'en' ? 'active': ''}`} 
    onClick={this.setState({lang: 'en'})}
  >
  ENG
  </a>
</li>
```

then you just need to write css for class `active`
for the second question change the `hover` css for li tags

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in `this.changeLan` you change a property `this.active` to `this.ita` or `this.eng`:
You can try

```js
<li>
  <a 
    className={`list-item ${this.active === this.ita ? 'active': ''}`} 
    onClick={this.changeLan.bind(this, this.ita)}
  >
  ITA
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a 
    className={`list-item ${this.active === this. eng ? 'active': ''}`} 
    onClick={this.changeLan.bind(this, this. eng)}
  >
  ENG
  </a>
</li>
```